# Limit of two variables with parametric powers of absolute values

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, parametric, parameter-estimation

I've been struggling with this exercise.
Edited
For every $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta \gt0 \in \mathbb R$, compute, if it
exists,
$$ \lim_{(x, y)\to (0,0)}  \frac {{\vert x \vert}^\alpha+ {\vert y \vert}^\beta}{{\vert x\vert}^\gamma + {\vert y \vert}^\delta} $$
In my opinion, if $\alpha=\beta$ and $\gamma=\delta$, the limit exists and can be 0, 1 or $\infty$ depending on $\alpha-\gamma$.
More specifically, if $\alpha=\beta$ and $\gamma=\delta$
we have $$\alpha\gt \gamma \Rightarrow\lim_{(x, y)\to (0,0)}{f(x,y)}=0 $$
$$\alpha= \gamma \Rightarrow\lim_{(x, y)\to (0,0)}{f(x,y)}=1 $$
$$\alpha\lt \gamma \Rightarrow\lim_{(x, y)\to (0,0)}{f(x,y)}=\infty $$.

Then we can say that if $\alpha \gt \gamma $ and $\beta \gt \delta $, using polar coordinates in the plane, triangle inequalities and company,
$${\vert f(x,y) \vert} \le {\vert \frac{{\rho^\alpha}{\vert \cos(t) \vert}^\alpha}{{\rho^\gamma}{\vert \cos(t) \vert}^\gamma} \vert}+ {\vert \frac{{\rho^\beta}{\vert \sin(t) \vert}^\beta}{{\rho^\delta}{\vert \sin(t) \vert}^\delta} \vert}\le \rho^{\alpha-\gamma}{{\vert \cos(t) \vert}^{\alpha-\gamma}}+ \rho^{\beta-\delta}{{\vert \sin(t) \vert}^{\beta-\delta}}$$,
thus the limit is 0 by the squeeze theorem.

Else, if $\alpha \lt \gamma $ and $\beta \lt \delta $
we can do the same as before (changing the roles of $\alpha, \gamma$ and $\beta, \delta$), applying the squeeze theorem to $\vert \frac {1}{f(\rho, t)} \vert \le 0 $ and prove lim=$\infty$.

Moreover, if $ (\alpha-\gamma)(\beta-\delta)\lt 0 $, our limit does not exist, because, restricting our function to the axis X and Y, we have
$\lim_{x\to 0} {\vert x\vert}^{\alpha - \gamma} \neq \lim_{y\to 0} {\vert y\vert}^{\beta - \delta}$
.
Are there any flaws or mistakes?
Is there something I'm not considering?
Many thanks

Comment: +1 : intriguing question.  My (**blind instinct**), which could **easily be wrong**, is that you are mistaken.  It seems to me, that when $\alpha > \gamma$ and $\beta > \delta$, then the fraction is (in effect) approaching $0$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$.  Under this **blind instinct**, it doesn't matter at what *angle* $(x,y) \to (0,0).$  As I say, I could easily be wrong.

Comment: You're correct (although I would do a slightly different polar coordinates construction) that the limit is $0$ when $\alpha>\gamma$ and $\beta>\delta$.  If either one fails to hold then the limit will not exist. (I'm not considering $\infty$ as a possible limit.) You have neglected the case $\alpha=\gamma$ and $\beta=\gamma$, where the limit will depend on the angle, yes.