# Limit of two variables with ln

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, solution-verification

I'm feeling a bit disappointed with my exercise book.
It says that these two limits do not exist, and I can't prove why.
$$ \lim_{(x, y) \to (0,0)} x\ln(y) $$

$$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0,0)} (\cos(x) - 1)\ln(y) $$
Polar coordinates didn't help me, and I would say the limit is 0 in both of them.
What am I not considering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one consider $x=t$ and $y=e^{-1/t}$ as $t\to 0^+$

$$x\ln y=-1$$

For the second one consider $x=t$ and $y=e^{-1/t^2}$ and refer to standard limits.

Comment: Could you please give a look to this one?  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3848709/limit-of-two-variables-with-four-parameters?noredirect=1#comment7939509_3848709

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For a given function $f$, if $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)$ exists, then $$\lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{y\to 0}f(x,y)=\lim_{y\to 0}\lim_{x\to 0}f(x,y).$$